# Why is my list appearing under my section instead of in it?

Tags: html, css

this might be a dumb question but i made a ul for my a footer but it is appearing under the section not in it. I don't know how to move it right next to my picture. Image is attached [The footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HczdL.png)

```css
#footer {
  background: #fdded9;
  height: 150px;
  width: 960px
}

.footerpic {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.copyright {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  font-size 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div class="footerpic">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logotransparent.png" alt="pic3" width="100" height="100" /></a>

    <ul class="copyright">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>The Team</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Privacy Policy</li>
    </ul>

</section>
```

Please help i don't know how to move it and i don't want any white space under my footer if it stuffs up!

Comment: Your use of the id "footer" suggests you should probably be using `<footer>` and not `<section>`

Answer (score 0):

You set `height: 150px;` on the section.

Since the content is taller than 150px, it overflows out of the box.

Leave the height at `auto` if you want it to expand to contain the content.

Answer (score 0):

Because you made your `footer` of `height:150px`.Your content exceeds that value. If you delete it everything must be as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the height on the section which is restricting the background height.

You might also want to close the  after the list.

```
   #footer {
      background: #fdded9;
      height: auto; /* 150px */
      width: 960px
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `display` on `#copyright` from `block` to `inline-block`. Then adjust the vertical align of the image. Setting the display to block causes the `ul` to show up on the next line from the image.

```css
#footer {
  background: #fdded9;
  height: 150px;
  width: 960px
}

.footerpic {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.footerpic img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

ul.copyright {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  font-size 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div class="footerpic">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logotransparent.png" alt="pic3" width="100" height="100" /></a>

    <ul class="copyright">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>The Team</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Privacy Policy</li>
    </ul>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left` to CSS
See snippet.

```css
#footer {
  background: #fdded9;
  height: 150px;
  width: 960px
}

.footerpic {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.copyright {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  font-size 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div class="footerpic">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logotransparent.png" alt="pic3" width="100" height="100" /></a>
  </div>
    <ul class="copyright">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>The Team</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Privacy Policy</li>
    </ul>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline block instead of display block to make it in one line like this

```
#footer {
    background: #fdded9;
    height:150px;
    width:960px
 }

.footerpic {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
 }

ul.copyright {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
   font-size 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `.footerpic` a `flex` row and it will put the children elements side-by-side, and you can use other flex properties if you want for separation, alignment, etc. Here is a good reference https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
#footer {
  background: #fdded9;
  height: 150px;
  width: 960px
}

.footerpic {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.copyright {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  font-size 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div class="footerpic">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logotransparent.png" alt="pic3" width="100" height="100" /></a>

    <ul class="copyright">
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>The Team</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Privacy Policy</li>
    </ul>

</section>
```